# Magnetic field strength of a magnetic dipole

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

We can calculate the electric field of a electric dipole:

[image]

where qc is the electric dipole moment and k is the Coulomb's costant.

Which is the equivalent for the magnetic field(H) of a magnetic dipole?

Comment: Isn't the answer readily available anywhere on the internet?

Comment: Read Wikipedia. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole